# How can I set the release apk file name in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, apk, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I saw some examples where they put this block of code inside the buildtypes block of build.gradle(app).

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "My Application"
            }
        }
```

But it's not working for me. I'm getting type mismatch (Required: Boolean, Found: Unit) although I've selected the "Unit" one.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXaih.png)

Answer (score 3):

```
applicationVariants.all {
    val variant = this
    variant.outputs
        .map { it as com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.BaseVariantOutputImpl }
        .forEach { output ->
            val outputFileName = "xxx-${variant.baseName}-${variant.versionName}-${variant.versionCode}.apk"
            output.outputFileName = outputFileName
        }
}
```

eg：output-> xxx-release-1.0.0-1.apk

Answer (score 1):

you can try creating variable in build file and creating own file naming like this

```
android {  
   applicationVariants.configureEach { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        //create build number
        def flavor = "DEMO" // Eg. TEST/LIVE/DEMO
        if (!android.buildTypes.debug.debuggable) {
            def newBuildNumber = getBuildNumber()
            versionCodeOverride = newBuildNumber
            versionNameOverride = "136.1.$newBuildNumber"
            flavor = "LIVE"
        }
        def ApkName
        def project = "your name"
        def SEP = "_"
        def mode = "ONLINE" // Eg. ONLINE/OFFLINE
        def version = variant.versionName
        def date = new Date();
        def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMdd')
        ApkName = project + SEP + mode + SEP + flavor + SEP + version + SEP 
        + formattedDate + ".apk"
        output.outputFileName = ApkName
    }
}
```

}

you can also increase build code version like this function will create build_number.txt file in your code directory and increase by 1 in every build you run.

```
 `def getBuildNumber() {
   if (!android.buildTypes.debug.debuggable) {
    def buildNumberFile = file('build_number.txt')
    if (buildNumberFile.exists()) {
        def lastBuildNumber = buildNumberFile.text.toInteger()
        def newBuildNumber = lastBuildNumber + 1
        buildNumberFile.text = newBuildNumber.toString()
        return newBuildNumber
       } else {
        buildNumberFile.text = '1'
        return 1
      }
   }
```

}`

> you can add getBuildNumber() function at the beginning of the gradle
> outside of `android {}`

**happy coding **

Answer (score 0):

Here, applicationVariants.all iterates over all the build variants. The outputs.all then iterates over all the outputs for that variant, allowing you to set the outputFileName for each.

```
import com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType

 plugins {
  id("com.android.application")
}

 android {
compileSdkVersion(30)

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion(16)
    targetSdkVersion(30)
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}

applicationVariants.all {
    outputs.all {
        val appName = "MyApplication"
        val versionName = this@all.versionName ?: "unknown"
        val versionCode = this@all.versionCode
        val variant = this@all.name
        val buildType = this@all.buildType.name
        outputFileName = "$appName-$versionName-$versionCode-$variant-$buildType.apk"
    }
}}
```

Comment: Hmm.. Doesn't work for me. outputFileName is an unresolved reference. BaseVariantOutput class doesn't have that property to set.